# Rails: No 'field_with_errors' when using 'fields_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

So, I have this nested 'organization' model in my 'user' model.
The user model is a devise based model and the organization belongs_to user.

I created a form for it, and everything works fine.
Even the 'devise_error_messages!' output everything correctly.

Only problems are localization and the field_with_errors-div..

I managed to get localization right by doing this in my locale file:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        contact:
          account_number: "bankrekening nummer"
```

Of course I just want it to work without 'contact' being in the 'user' list.

But the serious problem I'm having here is the 'field_with_errors' div witch is normally wrapped around the fields with errors.. I use it to create red colored labels on fields with errors.. They work for the user class, but they won't work for the nested forms..

Google isn't helping anything, like no one is having this issue except for me..

Is this even possible?

If it is, can you point me in the right direction of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having trouble getting the field_with_errors inserting for fields in a fields_for scope.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Use this and it works:

```
<%= f.fields_for :organization, (user.organization || user.build_organization) do |organization_form|
  ...
<% end %>
```

Note the `user.organization ||` part: if the organization has been already built, you shouldn't re-build it or you will lose your errors and the field_with_errors-div won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and I fixed it by adding `validates_associated :child_model` to *parent* model.